# Why does Ruby's Fixnum#/ method round down when it is called on another Fixnum?

Tags: ruby

Okay, so what's up with this?

```
irb(main):001:0> 4/3
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> 7/8
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> 5/2
=> 2
```

I realize Ruby is doing integer division here, but why? With a langauge as flexible as Ruby, why couldn't `5/2` return the actual, mathematical result of `5/2`? Is there some common use for integer division that I'm missing? It seems to me that making `7/8` return `0` would cause more confusion than any good that might come from it is worth. Is there any real reason why Ruby does this?

Comment: Integer division is no less "actual and mathematical" than division over rational or real numbers.

Comment: Yes, but mathematically speaking, 4/3 does not usually denote integer division. According to [this website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), integer division is usually represented by a backslash.

Comment: Ruby (and many languages) already use the backslash for other things, such as escaping special characters: In this case, using it for integer division may cause many headaches for the developper and for the parser (Some script languages use `//`).

Comment: @Eureka True. I'm not suggesting integer division be implemented that way, (I would probably use a method like Fixnum#quotient or something) I'm just saying that forward slash doesn't usually denote integer division, so doing it that way is rather confusing.

Comment: Just for future you reference you can force floating point precision by doing appending a decimal so 4.0/3 returns => 1.3333333333333333

Comment: If you `require 'mathn'`, you get `Rational`s with the `/` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because most languages (even advanced/high-level ones) in creation do it? You will have the same behaviour on integer in C, C++, Java, Perl, Python... This is [Euclidian Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) (hence the corresponding modulo `%` operator).

The integer division operation is even implemented at hardware level on many architecture. [Others](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/blogitem-040804-1) have asked this question, and one reason is symetry: In static typed languages such as see, this allows all integer operations to return integers, without loss of precision. It also allow easy access to the corresponding low-level assembler operation, since C was designed as a sort of extension layer over it.

Moreover, as explained in one comment to the linked article, floating point operations were costly (or not supported on all architectures) for many years, and not required for processes such as splitting a dataset in fixed lots.

Comment: First off, not *all* other languages do it this way, Common Lisp for example keeps fractions that don't simplify to integers as rationals and it's not the only language that does that. This also doesn't require use of floats, which invalidates your last paragraph a bit. Of course you are still spot on about the mapping to CPU instructions.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Manipulating rational numbers is ALSO costly compared to integers, albeit for different reasons.

Comment: @MichaelKohl The "all" was more a figure of speach than a litteral statement of fact, but I clarified the formulation, thanks ;)

Comment: So it's more of a familiarity thing? I guess I can sort of understand that. Judging by the number of questions I see on StackOverflow on this topic though, I still think that's a confusing way to handle division.

Comment: @Ajedi32 This is a confusing way the first time you discover a programming language, but this becomes expected behaviour if you already know one (barring exceptions such as Lisp): Since a language designer already know how to program, it is more tempting (and human) for him to transpose familiar concepts to his new language than to introduce new ones, except if they are one of the motivations for creating them in the first place.